# Problema con replace() con mayúsculas y minúsculas acentuadas en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

quiero hacer un replace de vocales mayúsculas y minúsculas acentuadas la misma letra sin acentuar en una cadena:

```
select replace(
replace(
 replace(
  replace(
   replace(
    replace(
     replace(
      replace(
       replace(
        replace('ÁéxÍvcú', 'á', 'a'), 
        'é', 'e'), 
       'í', 'i'), 
      'ó', 'o'), 
     'ú', 'u'), 
    'Á', 'A'), 
   'É', 'E'), 
  'Í', 'I'), 
 'Ó', 'O'), 
'Ú', 'U');
```

El problema que hay es que las mayúsculas las reemplaza por la letra minúscula correspondiente sin acentuar.

En este caso, necesito que la cadena `ÁéxÍvcú` sea reemplazada por `AexIcu` y el resultado que me devuelve la query es `aexivcu`

¿Alguna ayuda? Gracias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo mejor es que te olvides de replace y utilices [COLLATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms184391(v=sql.120).aspx):

```
select 'ÁéxÍvcú' collate SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CS_AS
```

> Es una cláusula que se puede aplicar a una definición de base de datos
>   o a una definición de columna para definir la intercalación, **o a una
>   expresión de cadena de caracteres para aplicar una conversión de
>   intercalación**.